# Weka: Does training helps if test run is followed by training run?

Tags: classification, weka, bayesian

I have a doubt. I understood the cross validation and split concept where the classifier will learn from the training data and test on test data split.

Does the same thing happen if I first run the classification with "Use training data" and then follow up with "SUpplied test set" option in classify tab and run again.

TO make it more clear here in classify tab I am running twice ...first with training data set uploaded under preprocess tab and then ran with test set uploaded in classify tab "Supplied test set" optoin. So while executing on test data does the model use the training done before?

I used naive bayes classifier. Also I have doubt like does all clasifiers learn from training data or just classifiers like Neural network, decision trees does?

Answer (score 2):

The options you speak of in the "classify tab" allow you to choose how to evaluate the model that has been built.  Each time you push "start" in the classify tab a new classifier is constructed.  For the options you listed, this classifier will use the entirety of the current dataset from the Preprocess tab. **Regardless if you supply a test dataset, or use the training data, the same classifier will be built**.  Weka will not use any information from a previously built classifier when constructing a new one, at least in the manner you described.

The difference between the two testing options are as follows:

1. "Use training data" will use the constructed classifier to predict the training instances.  This option usually gives overly optimistic estimates of the classifier's future performance.
2. "Supplied test set" will use an independent test set.  Given that this test set was constructed in a fair way, you should get an unbiased estimate of your classifier's future performance.

To address your last question, most classifiers try to induce a model from training data.  That is typically considered learning.  However, **some classifiers, such as IBk, do not induce a model, but rather use the training data itself to make future predictions**.  These are rather fine points, and it may be best just to say all **Weka classifiers make predictions informed by the training data.**

Comment: I see your point. But I found a way to do use the same training model to run on test data. See below for steps:  1) Run the classifier on training data. Once you run it appears in the result node. 2) Use the "Supplied test set" option to supply the test data. 3) Now under the Results section select the model which ran previously for training data. Righ click on it and select "Re-evaluate model on current test set" option.

Comment: That is good to know that that is an option.  Of course, doing that procedure would not change how the model is built, just how it is evaluated.  Building a model with "Use training set selected" and then saying re-evaluate with supplied test set creates the same model as selecting "supplied test" set in the first place.